# Insert data into three table by using JPA @onetomany and @manytoone annotation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert data into three different tables by using JPA Repository with spring boot application. for this purpose i used @onetomany and @manytoone annotation in these three classes:

1. HouseHold
2. OwnerDetails
3. HouseHoldMembers

but when i am trying to insert i am getting the following error.

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        household 
    where
        sl_no = ?
2019-10-16 12:24:46.622  INFO 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.o.a.a.s.FormServiceImpl                : FormServiceImpl saveHouseDetailsWithBase64() is invoked : 234546674
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('house_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('owner_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('mem_id_seq')
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        household
        (area, audio, district, east, gp_name, grid_no, house_dimension, house_photo, id, id_number, id_photo, Khatha_no, latitute, locality_name, longitute, map_photo, north, phone_num, pin, prop_details, prop_type, rent_amount, road_name, sl_no, south, servey_date, survey_no, surveyor_name, taluk, tenant, toilet_available, total_members, vacant_port, village_name, water_facility, west, hid) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        ownerdetails
        (age, education, gender, hid, idname, idnumber, name, oid) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-10-16 12:24:46.832  WARN 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2019-10-16 12:24:46.832 ERROR 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : ERROR: null value in column "hid" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, 10, education, male, adhaarcard1, 23424242343, name, null).
2019-10-16 12:24:46.840 ERROR 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [hid]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2019-10-16 12:24:46.848 ERROR 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.o.a.a.s.FormServiceImpl                : could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [hid]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
2019-10-16 12:24:46.849  INFO 19380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.o.a.a.c.FormDataController             : FormDataController saveHouseHold() request is completed.
```

HouseHold.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "household")
public class HouseHold implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "house_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "house_id_seq", sequenceName = "house_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "hid")
    private Long hid;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "district")
    private String district;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "taluk")
    private String taluk;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "village_name")
    private String villageName;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "sl_no")
    private Long slNo;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "Khatha_no")
    private String khathaNo;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "locality_name")
    private String localityName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "prop_details")
    private String propertyDetails;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "tenant")
    private String tenant;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "house_dimension")
    private String houseDimension;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "east")
    private String east;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "west")
    private String west;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "north")
    private String north;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "south")
    private String south;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2)
    @Column(name = "rent_amount")
    private BigDecimal rentAmount;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "vacant_port")
    private String vacantPort;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "gp_name")
    private String gpName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "prop_type")
    private String propertyType;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "road_name")
    private String roadName;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "pin")
    private Long pin;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "survey_no")
    private Long surveyNo;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "grid_no")
    private String gridNo;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 250)
    @Column(name = "id_number")
    private String idNumber;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "area")
    private String area;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 3)
    @Column(name = "toilet_available")
    private String toiletAvailable;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 3)
    @Column(name = "water_facility")
    private String waterFacility;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "phone_num")
    private Long phoneNumber;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "house_photo")
    private String housephoto;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_photo")
    private String idphoto;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "map_photo")
    private String mapphoto;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "audio")
    private String audio;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 25)
    @Column(name = "latitute")
    private BigDecimal latitude;
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 25)
    @Column(name = "longitute")
    private BigDecimal longitude;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "surveyor_name")
    private String surveyorName;
    @Column(name = "servey_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date surveyDate;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "total_members")
    private String totalMembers;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @JsonIgnore
    @Transient
    private String serveyStringDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "houseHold", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OwnerDetails> ownerdetail = new ArrayList<>();
//default constructor
//parameterized constructor
//getter setter
```

OwnerDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ownerdetails")
public class OwnerDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "owner_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "owner_id_seq", sequenceName = "owner_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "oid")
    private Long oid;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "education")
    private String education;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "idname")
    private String idName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "idnumber")
    private String idNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hid", referencedColumnName = "hid", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private HouseHold houseHold;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ownerdetails", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<HouseHoldMembers> membersdetails = new ArrayList<>();
    //default constructor
    //parameterized constructor
    //getter setter
```

HouseHoldMembers.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "household_members")
public class HouseHoldMembers implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "mem_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "mem_id_seq", sequenceName = "mem_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "mid")
    private Long mid;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "education")
    private String education;
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 10)
    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "idname")
    private String idName;
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "idnumber")
    private String idNumber;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "oid", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = true)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private OwnerDetails ownerdetails;
        //default constructor
        //parameterized constructor
        //getter setter
```

Dtat.json

```
{
    "district" : "district",
    "taluk" : "taluk",
    "villageName" : "village name",
    "slNo" : 234546674,
    "khathaNo" : "35824005",
    "localityName" : "localitiyname",
    "propertyDetails" : "property Details",
    "tenant" : "tenant",
    "houseDimension" : "housedimension",
    "east":"east",
    "west":"west",
    "north":"north",
    "south":"south",
    "rentAmount":2000.45,
    "vacantPort":"2342",
    "gpId":23112,
    "gpName":"gpname",
    "propertyType":"proprty type",
    "roadName":"road name",
    "pin":700003,
    "surveyNo":23122,
    "gridNo":"23122",
    "idNumber":"2321223232232",
    "area":"area",
    "toiletAvailable":"yes",
    "waterFacility":"yes",
    "phoneNumber":9999999999,

    "housephoto":"",

    "mapphoto":"",

    "audio":"",

    "latitude":"22.453",
    "longitude":"88.453",
    "surveyorName":"surveyor name",
    "serveyStringDate":"2019-10-13 11:25:36",
    "totalMembers":"2",
    "id":1,

    "ownerdetail":
    [ 
        {
            "name":"name",
            "education":"education",
            "age":10,
            "gender":"male",
            "idName":"adhaarcard1",
            "idNumber":"23424242343",
            "membersdetails":
            [
                {
                    "name":"name",
                    "education":"education",
                    "age":10,
                    "gender":"male",
                    "idName":"adhaarcard2",
                    "idNumber":"23424242344"
                },
                {
                    "name":"name1",
                    "education":"education1",
                    "age":11,
                    "gender":"male",
                    "idName":"adhaarcard2",
                    "idNumber":"23424242344"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

also i created repository classes for each entity class. Can someone please help me to solve this error. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: How are you generating value for "hid" ?
The error says: ERROR: null value in column "hid" violates not-null constraint

Comment: For this i created a get method in OwnerDetails class  public Long getHid() {
  return houseHold.getHid();
 } which is return HouseHold hid value but it is not working.

Comment: Is the "hid" column an Auto Increment value?
The get method is not going to generate a new value for "hid". You need to either generate "hid" or let database take care of it.

Comment: from my side how will it generate? actually in HouseHold class i used @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) which is working properly but in OwnerDetails class where i used @ManyToOne annotation with HouseHold object here it is not getting value so it is giving error. do you have any  idea what should i do.

Comment: when i remove nullable = false from @JoinColumn annotation than data is inserting into all three tables but value is null set in foreign key column into ownerdetails and householdmembers table.

Answer (score 0):

[JPA Examplem][One to many and many to one relationship][https://github.com/kuldeepjha/JpaProject/tree/master/demo ]

Comment: Explain the answer in words, please. Link-only answers lost sense when links outdate.